# How to deal with xml_missing when using Rvest and html_element?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'd like to make a list out of every election date listed here: https://voterportal.sos.la.gov/static/
so that I can then travel to each respective election site and download and compile the spreadsheets called "Excel - Complete Results"

Normally I'd go about this by using Rvest to get every date listed on the linked site and then map over the dates to get to each elections sites (just the election date appended to the parent site url like: "https://voterportal.sos.la.gov/static/2022-04-30") and then read in the excels that are linked in the election sites but I'm running into a problem with `html_elements` that I haven't encountered before:

I tried to use `html_elements` to pull the dates:

```
la_elections_url <- "https://voterportal.sos.la.gov/static/"

la_elections_text <- read_html(la_elections_url)

la_elections_text %>% html_element("a")
```

Which I thought I'd be able to filter to the `href` attributes like:

```
html_attr(html_nodes(la_elections_text, "a"), "href") %>% as.list()
```

To get a list of the election dates but I get the warning:

```
la_elections_text %>% html_element("a")

{xml_missing}
<NA>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This website uses XHR to load data, which makes using `rvest` based on the DOM a bit trickier. Luckily, you can use DevTools to grab the URL to fetch all of the data yourself:

[image]

Using `httr`, this becomes pretty easy:

```
library(httr)
library(tidyverse)


res <- httr::GET('https://voterportal.sos.la.gov/ElectionResults/ElectionResults/Data?blob=ElectionDates.htm')

res_list <- httr::content(res)

res_list$Dates$Date %>% 
  purrr::map( ~ {
    .x$ElectionDate
  })
```

Which gives you:

```
[[1]]
[1] "04/29/2023"

[[2]]
[1] "03/25/2023"

[[3]]
[1] "02/18/2023"

[[4]]
[1] "01/14/2023"

[[5]]
[1] "12/10/2022"

.....
```

Comment: Damn, speedier than me! +1, and worth noting that you can do this with just rvest too. And you don't need the whole tidyverse, just `purrr`: `jsonlite::fromJSON(html_text(html_element(read_html("https://voterportal.sos.la.gov/ElectionResults/ElectionResults/Data?blob=ElectionDates.htm"), "p")))`

Comment: Oh nice solution! I added `tidyverse` so the pipe is included, but certainly fine to just use `purrr` and `magrittr` or just not use a pipe.